# create multiple files made up of a range of values

Tags: command-line, echo

Using linux command line I wish to create multiple text files with variables a,b,c increasing by a set range each time with a particular max., as below

txt file 1

```
a 2
b 1 
c 3
```

txt file 2

```
a 3
b 2
c 4
```

txt file 3

```
a 4
b 3 
c 5
```

so far I only have understood

```
until [$array[0] -gt 10 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple `for` loop ex.:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do 
  printf 'a %d\nb %d\nc %d\n' $((1+i)) $((0+i)) $((2+i)) > file${i}
done
```

giving

```
$ head file{1..3}
==> file1 <==
a 2
b 1
c 3

==> file2 <==
a 3
b 2
c 4

==> file3 <==
a 4
b 3
c 5
```